# ```while [List]: ``` vs ```while [List] is True```? What is the difference?

Tags: python, while-loop

`while [List]:`   vs `while [List] is True`? What is the different?

For example I am doing this problem (heap and priority queues) https://leetcode.com/problems/find-k-pairs-with-smallest-sums/ and here is a sample solution that I retrieved. I do not understand this line `while len(res) < k and heap:`. Why do I need `while heap:`? and Also when I tried `while ... heap is True`, the code no longer works.

```
class Solution:
    """Returns List[List[int]]"""

    def kSmallestPairs(self, nums1, nums2, k):
        # nums1 and nums2 are both sorted list
        res = []
        if not nums1 or not nums2 or not k:
            return res

        heap = []
        visited = set()


        heapq.heappush(heap, (nums1[0] + nums2[0], 0, 0))
        visited.add((0, 0))


        while len(res) < k and heap:
            _, i, j = heapq.heappop(heap)
            res.append([nums1[i], nums2[j]])

            if i + 1 < len(nums1) and (i + 1, j) not in visited:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (nums1[i + 1] + nums2[j], i + 1, j))
                visited.add((i + 1, j))

            if j + 1 < len(nums2) and (i, j + 1) not in visited:
                heapq.heappush(heap, (nums1[i] + nums2[j + 1], i, j + 1))
                visited.add((i, j + 1))
        return res
```

Comment: You want to check the "truthiness" of heap.   you can see that `bool([])` and `bool{[1])` return different values, so when a list is used as a boolean value, the empty list will return `False` and non-empty will return `True`

Comment: @j1-lee What about while [list] is True? I tried this and I didn't work but while [list]: works?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different things necessary to fully understand the topic you're asking about.

The first is what do the `is` operator does. It checks for identity, that is, if `A is B` is true, then `A` and `B` must be two references to the same object.

The second is boolean contexts. When you use an expression in a `if` or `while` statement's condition, or pass it as the first argument to the `and` or `or` operators (or the only argument to the unary `not` operator), Python will implicitly convert your object into a `bool` value before considering if the condition is passed or not. Different types may handle this conversion differently, by implementing whatever logic they want in their `__bool__` method. For the builtin types, `bool(o)` is `False` only for numerical values that are equal to zero, and for container objects that are empty (and `None` is always falsey). All other values are truthy (as are instances of user-created classes, by default).

Note the terminology I'm using here. When dealing with boolean contexts, we often talk about "truthiness" rather than something *being* true or false. An object `o` is "truthy" if `bool(o)` is `True`, and "falsey" if `bool(o)` is `False`. A truthy value isn't generally equal to `True`. And while a bunch of numerical falsey values are equal to `False` (because `False` is equal to zero), other kinds of falsey values (like empty strings and empty lists) are not equal to either zero or `False`.

In the code you're asking about, a list named `heap` is tested in a boolean context. That means the condition will be true (and the `while` loop will keep going) if the list is non-empty. You can see why that's important by looking at the very first line of the loop body, where `heapq.heappop` is called on the list. That function will raise an exception if `heap` is empty, so the code stops the loop if that's the case.

Testing `heap is False` is not remotely equivalent, because `heap`  is a list, and so it will never be a reference to the same object as the `False` literal. In some situations it might make sense for a loop condition to use `is`, but this is definitely not one of those situations.

Writing `bool(heap) is True` could make some amount of sense, but it's unnecessary, since just `heap` (in the context of a `while` loop's condition) works just as well.

If you want to be more explicit about the check, you could test the length of the list directly, with `len(heap) > 0`. This is also longer than just using `heap` by itself, but it might be worth writing anyway if you feel it is more expressive of the meaning you intend (though experienced Python programmers will understand what `heap` means in a boolean context).

(I'd further note that your question was a bit more confusing than it needed to be because you're using `[List]` as a sort of pseudocode meaning "some kind of list", despite the fact that that string is valid Python syntax. Without your textual explanation, I'd expect `[List]` to mean a one-element list containing a value named `List`, which would always be truthy, since it's not empty. Avoiding ambiguous notation in your questions will help you get quicker and better answers to your questions.)

Answer (score 0):

any data can be `True` or `False` 
remember this:
`0` -> `False` (but be care `'0'` as string is True, because it's a string that not equal to '' empty one) 
`''` -> `False` (empty string = False)
`[]` -> `False` (empty list, empty tuple, empty set, empty dict = False)

`[]` - this is `False` 
`['something']` - this is `True`

so when you see things like this: `if [list]` or `while [list]`
you should see them like:
`if [this list is not empty]`
`while [this list is not empty == while it's True]`

so this `while len(res) < k and heap` means:
while length of res < k and heap is True (-> not empty, not 0, not False)

Comment: Thanks how about [list] is not None? How is that different from [list] is not False (ie True)

Comment: `[list]` (i mean empty list) is False , and by `[empty_list] is not False` you check it like `False is not False` , False is actually False (-> True), so this expression is False by itself. for about `[empty_list] is not None` it's always is not None and it doesn't matter if it's empty or not. list can be False (if it's empty) or True (if it's not) but it can't be None.

Comment: Thank you. What about ```while [list] is True```? I tried this and I didn't work but ```while [list]: ```works? Why are they different? and my list contains 'something'.

Comment: `while []:` and `while [] is True:` are the same thing, there is no difference between them, they both 'closes' `while` loop.

Comment: Are you sure? Why does my python console give difference result? Try it yourself, the first while loop runs but not the second. ```L = [1]``` and then ```while L: print(l)``` and ```while L is True: print(l)```

Comment: I'm sure about this `while []:` and `while [] is True:` you say about different thing if `L=[1]` then L is not empty list -> l == True. => `while L` is the same as `while True`, and `while L is True ` is the same like `while True is True`